# extract date from one text file and write to new file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file like the one given below, and I'm looking for a way to read line 2 to line 7 and write it to a new file using Python.

```html
16 processes; 52 threads;
CPU states: 0.0% user, 0.0% kernel
CPU  0 Idle: 99.9%
CPU  1 Idle: 99.7%
CPU  2 Idle: 100.0%
CPU  3 Idle: 100.0%
Memory: 1024M total, 854M avail, page size 4K

      PID   TID PRI STATE    HH:MM:SS    CPU  COMMAND
        1    15  10 Run       0:00:00   0.03% kernel
    28688     1  10 Rply      0:00:00   0.02% top
       11     2  21 Rcv       0:00:00   0.00% io-pkt-v6-hc
        4     2  10 NSlp      0:00:00   0.00% random
        6     1  24 Rcv       0:00:00   0.00% devc-serscif
        1    18  10 Rcv       0:00:00   0.00% kernel
    28686     1  10 SigW      0:00:00   0.00% devb-sdmmc-rcar_mmcif
    28684     1  10 SigW      0:00:00   0.00% qconn
        1    16  10 Rcv       0:00:00   0.00% kernel
        2     1  10 Rcv       0:00:00   0.00% slogger2

             Min        Max       Average
CPU 0 idle:   99%        99%        99%
CPU 1 idle:   99%        99%        99%
CPU 2 idle:  100%       100%       100%
CPU 3 idle:  100%       100%       100%
Mem Avail:   854MB      854MB      854MB
Processes:    16         16         16
Threads:      52         52         52
```

i want  to find a way to save this part in new text file.

```html
CPU states: 0.0% user, 0.0% kernel
CPU  0 Idle: 99.9%
CPU  1 Idle: 99.7%
CPU  2 Idle: 100.0%
CPU  3 Idle: 100.0%
Memory: 1024M total, 854M avail, page size 4K
```

i ma not familier with python and not a programmer, can anybody help me?

best regards

Comment: You could try by splitting the data by `\n` and separate list index from 1-6

Comment: Why not just `sed '2,7!d' path/to/your/file`?

Comment: Just FYI, unless Python is a requirement here, this is a very simple operation that does not require Python, you can do it straight in a Linux shell. Use "head" to get the first N lines, use > to extract the output to a new file. Example: "head -n 6 > output.txt"

Comment: @pzkpfw while i agree with using a bash utility rather that a whole script, this would include the very first line, that should be omitted as requested by OP. so it is not quite as simple as using head and piping, zwers approach looks about right to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a simple iteration.

**Ex:**

```
with open(filename) as infile, open(filename2, "w") as outfile:
    next(infile)
    for _ in range(6):
        outfile.write(next(infile))
```

**Output:**

```
CPU states: 0.0% user, 0.0% kernel
CPU  0 Idle: 99.9%
CPU  1 Idle: 99.7%
CPU  2 Idle: 100.0%
CPU  3 Idle: 100.0%
Memory: 1024M total, 854M avail, page size 4K
```

Answer (score 0):

so this should be about right for what you want - although it sounds like something i would not employ python for, rather some bash commands...

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f: #open your file to read it
    file = f.readlines() #save lines of the file as list
with open('newfile.txt','w') as f: #open (create) an output file
    f.write(file[1:7]) #write the 2nd to 7th list elements in there (0-incremented)
```

Comment: as for the alternative bash commands, @zwer has given a sed example in the questions comments.

Comment: ***This is wrong***, as `file[1:6]` will return the 2nd to **6th** list elements

Comment: Also, no need for `.read().split('\n')` as `python` already has the `.readlines()` method for files, which will produce the same result and will be more efficient.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
with open('first_file.txt', 'r') as file1, open('second_file.txt', 'a') as file2:
    lines = file1.readlines()
    file2.write("".join(lines[1:7]))
```

Note: This won't work well if your input file is very large.